# ComplexType Address disappears when i use an Expand in odata WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, odata

I have a complexType which looks like ( it's in Dutch)

```
namespace Omnisoft.Domain.ComplexTypes
{
//  <ComplexType> _[KnownType(typeof(Adres))]
[DataContract(IsReference = false, Namespace = "")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Adres))]
public class Adres
{
    public Adres()
    {
        AdresLijn1 = "";
        AdresLijn2 = "";
        PostCode = "";
        Gemeente = "";
        Land = "BE";
        // "BE"

        //<Client_Adres_AdresLijn1></Client_Adres_AdresLijn1>
        //<Client_Adres_AdresLijn2></Client_Adres_AdresLijn1>

    }

    [DataMember(), StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringMaxLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValRes.ValidationStrings))]
    [Display(Description="AdresLijn1", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.Address))]
    public string AdresLijn1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(), StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringMaxLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValRes.ValidationStrings))]
    [Display(Description="AdresLijn2", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.Address))]
    public string AdresLijn2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(), StringLength(10, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringMaxLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValRes.ValidationStrings))]
    [Display(Description="PostCode", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.Address))]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember(), StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringMaxLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValRes.ValidationStrings))]
    [Display(Description="Gemeente", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.Address))]
    public string Gemeente { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValRes.ValidationStrings))]
    [DataMember(), StringLength(2, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringMaxLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValRes.ValidationStrings))]
    [Display(Description="Land", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.Address))]
    public string Land { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string ToSingleLine
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AdresLijn2))
            {
                return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", AdresLijn1, PostCode, Gemeente);
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Format("{0}({1}) {2}", AdresLijn1, AdresLijn2, PostCode, Gemeente);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I haven't defined it anywhere now ( removed it from modelbuilder.ComplexType), for testing if the error dissapears, but i notice no difference in adding or removing [ComplexTypes]

This an example url:

Here is the result for url /v1/Supplier?apiKey=ca2d711d-31f0-4f14-9eb4-363921db894e&format=json&$top=1 : http://pastebin.com/CLzAeEFk ( notice it has an address)

Here is the result for url /v1/Supplier?apiKey=ca2d711d-31f0-4f14-9eb4-363921db894e&format=json&$top=1&$expand=TaxCode : http://pastebin.com/ysn6uMHA ( notice no address )

This is the error that i receive for url :     http://localhost:64829/v1/Supplier?apiKey=ca2d711d-31f0-4f14-9eb4-363921db894e&format=json&$top=1&$expand=TaxCode,Address

```
{  
"Message":"An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage":"Het doel van een aanroep heeft een uitzondering veroorzaakt.",
"ExceptionType":"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException",
"StackTrace":"   bij System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)\r\n   bij System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)\r\n   bij System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)\r\n   bij System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)\r\n   bij System.Web.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.LimitResults(IQueryable queryable, Int32 limit, Boolean& resultsLimited)\r\n   bij System.Web.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(IQueryable query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)\r\n   bij System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   bij System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)\r\n   bij System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)\r\n   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---\r\n   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---\r\n   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---\r\n   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---\r\n   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   bij System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   bij System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
"InnerException":{  
  "Message":"An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage":"Cannot compare elements of type 'Omnisoft.Domain.ComplexTypes.Adres'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.",
  "ExceptionType":"System.NotSupportedException",
  "StackTrace":"   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.VerifyTypeSupportedForComparison(Type clrType, TypeUsage edmType, Stack`1 memberPath)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.CreateIsNullExpression(DbExpression operand, Type operandClrType)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.EqualsTranslator.CreateIsNullExpression(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression input)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.EqualsTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MemberInitTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MemberInitExpression linq)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MemberInitTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MemberInitExpression linq)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateSet(Expression linq)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.UnarySequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()\r\n   bij System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   bij System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   bij System.Web.OData.Query.TruncatedCollection`1..ctor(IQueryable`1 source, Int32 pageSize)\r\n   bij System.Web.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.LimitResults[T](IQueryable`1 queryable, Int32 limit, Boolean& resultsLimited)"
 }
 }
```

I don't receive the error when i remove Address from the expand function, but it doesn't show on the entity also...

Can you help me figure out the problem? So i can do an expand + show the complex type in my data structure?

I'm using EF 6.1.3, Asp.Net.MVC 5.2.3, Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.3, ODataLib 6.15.0 and Microsoft.AspNet.OData 5.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Complex type will be auto selected, and should not be part of $expand which is for navigation properties only.
2. I assume your Supplier has a property with type of Address, then when you get Supplier, the Address will be auto retrieved.

You can refer to this sample, 
http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(4xq3yia0dzts5gfflfp2sbt5))/TripPinServiceRW/People

We can see AddressInfo is a collection of complex type Location, it is auto selected.

If you still have issue, can you show metadata of supplier and address?

Comment: It's not autoselected when i expand something. It's autoselected when i don't use any $expand. The class Supplier ( Leverancier in Dutch) is pasted here http://pastebin.com/4TJzBtj7 ( because it's too long)

Comment: I am not sure which one is for Address (Adres?), can you help do these check,


1. Can you request ~/$metadata, and see whether Address is a ComplexType or EntityType?

2. When you said "It's not autoselected when i expand something", can you specify which property? And "It's autoselected when i don't use any $expand. ", what is auto selected?

3. What your expectation? If you want to select some complex type property and entity type property (navigation property), and you only need to specify entity type property in $expand.